# Java JTable print too small on higher resolution screens

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

Why's the font too small when I print a jtable in higher resolution screens? It looks perfectly fine on a 1600x900 but when I print the same table on a higher resolution screen like 1920x1200 the font becomes too small.

```
HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attr = null;

attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attr.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
attr.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
attr.add(new JobName(persistentPrintText, Locale.ENGLISH));

MediaSize mediaSize = MediaSize.ISO.A4;
float mediaWidth = mediaSize.getX(Size2DSyntax.MM);
float mediaHeight = mediaSize.getY(Size2DSyntax.MM);
float imageableX = 10; //mm left and right margins
float imageableY = 10; //mm top and bottom margins
float imageableWidth = (mediaWidth - (2 * imageableX));
float imageableHeight = (mediaHeight - (2 * imageableY));
MediaPrintableArea imageableArea = new MediaPrintableArea(
        imageableX, imageableY,
        imageableWidth, imageableHeight, Size2DSyntax.MM);
attr.add(imageableArea);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(jTableCivil1Info.getPrintable(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, new MessageFormat("Page {0}")));
if (job.printDialog(attr)) {
    try {
        job.print(attr);
    } catch (PrinterException pe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're printing the output to the screen or to the printer?  Printing to the printer "should" have little affect on the output, unless the font has been changed in the `JTable` itself. I've never had an issue with printing something across multiple platforms or resolutions

Comment: I'm printing to a printer. When I do, the font becomes really small on a higher resolution screen for some odd reason.

Comment: When printing - have a look at the font properties of the table